# Ways for heartbeat message

Tags: scala, akka, heartbeat

I am trying to set a heartbeat over a network, i.e. having an actor send a message to the network on a fixed period of time. I would like to know if you have any better solution than the one I used below as I feel is pretty ugly, considering synchronisation contraints.

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.Props
import akka.actor.ScalaActorRef
import akka.pattern.gracefulStop
import akka.util._
import java.util.Calendar
import java.util.concurrent._
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import scala.Array._
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

sealed trait Message
case class Information() extends Message//does really need to be here?
case class StartMessage() extends Message
case class HeartbeatMessage() extends Message
case class StopMessage() extends Message
case class FrequencyChangeMessage(
    f: Int
) extends Message

class Gps extends Actor {
    override def preStart() {
        val child = context.actorOf(Props(new Cadencer(500)), name = "cadencer")
    }
    def receive = {
        case "beat" =>
            //TODO
        case _      =>
            println("gps: wut?")
    }
}

class Cadencer(p3riod: Int) extends Actor {
    var period: Int = _
    var stop: Boolean = _
    override def preStart() {
        period = p3riod
        stop = false
        context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(period milliseconds, self, HeartbeatMessage)
    }
    def receive = {
        case StartMessage =>
            stop = false
            context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(period milliseconds, self, HeartbeatMessage)
        case HeartbeatMessage =>
            if (false == stop) {
                context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(0 milliseconds, context.parent, "beat")
                context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(period milliseconds, self, HeartbeatMessage)
            }
        case StopMessage =>
            stop = true
        case FrequencyChangeMessage(f) =>
            period = f
        case _  =>
            println("wut?\n")
            //throw exception
    }
}

object main extends App {
    val system = akka.actor.ActorSystem("mySystem")
    val gps = system.actorOf(Props[Gps], name = "gps")
}
```

What I called `cadencer` here sends to a target `actor` and to itself an `HeartbeatMessage` ; to itself to transmit the order to resend one after a given amount of time, and thus going on with the process till a `StopMessage` (flipping the `stop` to `true`). Good?

Is even having a separated `actor` efficient rather than having it within a greater one?

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It does not need a separate cadencer class.

```
class Gps extends Actor
{
  var ticker : Cancellable = _

  override def preStart()
  {
    println ("Gps prestart")
    // val child = context.actorOf(Props(new Cadencer(500)), name = "cadencer")
    ticker = context.system.scheduler.schedule (
      500 milliseconds,
      500 milliseconds,
      context.self,
      "beat")
  }

  def receive: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] =
  {
    case "beat" =>
      println ("got a beat")

    case "stop" =>
      ticker.cancel()

    case _ =>
      println("gps: wut?")
  }
}

object main extends App
{
  val system = akka.actor.ActorSystem("mySystem")
  val gps = system.actorOf(Props[Gps], name = "gps")

  Thread.sleep (5000)
  gps ! "stop"
  println ("stop")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actors are pretty lightweight, so it is no problem to have one actor for sending heartbeat messages (and it's preferable if you think of the Single Responsibility Principle).

Further remarks:

If you want to get rid of the period var, you can do the following (it's called hotswapping):

```
override def preStart() {
  // ...
  context.become(receive(p3riod))   
}

def receive(period: Int) = {
  // ...
  case FrequencyChangeMessage(f) =>
    context.become(receive(f))
  // ...
}
```

Instead of using the stop var, you can stop the actor after getting the StopMessage.
If you need a heartbeat actor again, just start a new one.

Instead of scheduling with 0 milliseconds, you can send the message directly to the parent.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I read what you advised me, I also read that once stopped an actor has no memory of his behavior nor his type when I restarts. I am facing a problem with this, since I want to be able to order the change of the heartbeat frequency... Moreover, what does this line in your code means? "context.become(receive(p3riod))".

Comment: It's called hotswapping (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.5/scala/actors.html#actor-hotswap). This way you can hotswap the actors message loop during runtime. The cool thing is: You can also use parameters (like period) and because of that you can get rid of a mutable var.